# How ajax works in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

How server decide that full page content need to be send to client or partial content?

Comment: There are many books that address this question. I do not think you can get a meaningful answer in a stackoverflow post.

Comment: @Jonathan: than what is the use of StackOverFlow ? If some one ask this question to you then what would u say ?

Comment: stackoverflow is to answer specific questions. But just as I wouldn't ask a question like "how do I program computers?", I feel about the same as asking "how does AJAX work?" I mean, are you asking how it works, how to use it, or what? A complete answer would and does fill a book.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: sorry but i must say that you have not read my question and description, its not like the way you thought. Generally most of people use update panel or other control of Ajax control tool kit. so didn't you think that they must know how it works?

Comment: It looks like I'm not the only one who had trouble know exactly what piece of information you wanted. I DID read your question. You can ignore my point if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what exactly are you asking - but assuming that you want to know ASP.NET Ajax internals. Essentially, ASP.NET code sniffs request for __ASYNCPOST form variable (or "X-MicrosoftAjax" request header) - this is used to decide if the request if regular post-back or asynchronous post-back. If asynchronous post-back then ScriptManager & UpdatePanel works together to decide which update-panels need to send their content to client.

Comment: thanks, your answer is quite good but not enough so can you please elaborate little bit more...

Comment: @Jeevan, I would suggest that you use reflector to see actual code from ScriptManager and UpdatePanel to get an idea. You can use Fiddler (or Firebug) to inspect AJAX request/response to understand what data goes and what comes in.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Updatepanle and scriptmanager than check below

1. Specify a Scriptmanager and Enable EnablePartialRendering.
2. Then specify your updatepanel for specific control you want to set for partial page update

Comment: thanks, but i could not understand your answer. I just want o know how ajax refresh partial page. basically how it work ?